# mat-accordion expansion panel not shown inside a mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular v6 and I have a grid list with an accordion inside each tile. When I expand an accordion, the panel is expanded but is not pushing the parent panel down.

You can see this example I created which demonstrates the problem I have.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruaw5w

Answer (score 0):

in your mat-grid-list you have rowHeight to 50px therefore your row is limited to this size. I'm not sure to understand the behaviour you want to achieve but I guess that increasing the size of your row may help you.